# v-for rendered component and <selection>, how to change it only for one instance of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I render some elements of array (that I get from backend) with v-for. I have a selection in every instance. When I select something, selection changes in all instances (obviously because of v-model). How can I target only one selection?

```
<div v-for="bookElement in searchResults.items"              :key="bookElement.id">

 <v-select
  v-model="book.selection"
  :items="book.items"
  label="Add to list" 
 ></v-select>

</div>

<script>
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      book: {
        title: null,
        author: null,
        genre: null,
        description: null,
        bookImage: null,
        googleBooksId: null,
        listType: null,
        selection: null,
        items: ["Reading now", "Want to read", "Finished"]
      }
    };
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's like you used vuetifyjs, so your select box must be like this

```
 <v-select
    v-model="selectedValue"
    :items="searchResults.items"
    label="Standard"
 ></v-select>
```

it is not needed `v-for`

Comment: I render not the options for selection element with v-for. I render my search results with v-for.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by rendering separate component as a search result instance.